# Getting permission denied from pexpect python module when doing ssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, pexpect

When i do a simple ssh (using a terminal) from one server to another then it works well but when i try using ssh from my python application using pexpect module then i am unable to do so. Any idea why is this happening ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pef.py", line 8, in <module>
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 316, in login
    raise ExceptionPxssh('permission denied')
pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: permission denied
```

I am using the example given in pexpect document

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.force_password = True
hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
username = raw_input('username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
s.login(hostname, username, password)
s.sendline('uptime')   # run a command
s.prompt()             # match the prompt
print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
s.sendline('ls -l')
s.prompt()
print(s.before)
s.sendline('df')
s.prompt()
print(s.before)
s.logout()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with an older version of pexpect module. Update the module using:

```
pip install pexpect --upgrade
```